# Trouble hitting the correct dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm new to Python and we have an assignment working with dictionaries and pickles.  We had to make a simple phonebook app, but I'm receiving a key error that I can't figure out.
Most of the options work, except for the first "Look up an entry".  It prompts me for a name (that I have previously pickled) I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phonebook.py", line 95, in <module>
    look_up()
  File "phonebook.py", line 25, in look_up
    info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
KeyError: 'lelani'
```

I've tired writing different things for the keys and I've also tried using phonebook_dict instead of info_dict but I continue to receive a KeyError.  Normally, I would run this through PythonTutor to catch my error, but since it's using dictionaries and unpickling, I can't.  Maybe I'm overthinking it or looking over something obvious, but I would really appreciate any insight.

Here's the code:

```
from os.path import exists

filename = "phonebook2.pickle"

if exists('phonebook.pickle'):
    print "Loading phonebook"
    phonebook_file = open("phonebook.pickle", "r")
    phonebook_dict = pickle.load(phonebook_file)
    phonebook_file.close()

else:
    phonebook_dict = {}

while True:
    #Looks up an entry
    def look_up():
        name = raw_input("Name? ")
        info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
        if name in info_dict: #how do i fix this?/ won't return set     contacts
        #info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
            print "Found entry for %s: " % (name)
            print "Cell Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Cell"])
            print "Home Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Home"])
            print "Work Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Work"])

        else:
            print "Entry for %s not found." % name

#Sets an entry
def set_entry():
    print "Please add the name and number to create a new entry:"
    name = raw_input("Name: ").strip()
    cell_phone = raw_input("Cell Phone Number? ")
    home_phone = raw_input("Home Phone Number? ")
    work_phone = raw_input("Work Phone Number? ")
    info_dict = {
        "Cell": cell_phone,
        "Home": home_phone,
        "Work": work_phone}
    phonebook_dict[name] = info_dict
    print "Entry stored for %s" % name


#Deletes an entry
def delete_entry():
    print "Please enter a name to delete from the phonebook."
    name = raw_input("Name: ").lower()
    if name in phonebook_dict:
        del phonebook_dict[name]
        print "Deleted entry for %s" % name
    else:
        print "%s not found." % name

#Lists all entries
def list_entries():
    for name, info_dict in phonebook_dict.items():
        print "Found entry for %s: " % (name)
        print "*" * 30
        print "Cell Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Cell"])
        print "Home Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Home"])
        print "Work Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Work"])
        print "*" * 30


#Saves all entries
def save_entries():
    phonebook_file = open("phonebook.pickle", "w")
    pickle.dump(phonebook_dict, phonebook_file)
    phonebook_file.close()
    print "Entries saved to the phonebook."


print """
Electronic Phone Book
=====================

1\. Look up an entry
2\. Set an entry
3\. Delete an entry
4\. List all entries
5\. Save entries
6\. Quit
"""

menu_number = int(raw_input("What do you want to do (1-6)? "))

if menu_number == 1:
    look_up()
elif menu_number == 2:
    set_entry()
elif menu_number == 3:
    delete_entry()
elif menu_number == 4:
    list_entries()
elif menu_number == 5:
    save_entries()
elif menu_number == 6:
    print "Goodbye!"
    break
elif menu_number > 6:
    print "Invalid option. Please enter a valid option (1-6)."
```

Also, phonebook.pickle for reference:

```
(dp0
S'Autumn'
p1
(dp2
S'Cell'
p3
S'111-111-1111'
p4
sS'Home'
p5
S'222-222-2222'
p6
sS'Work'
p7
S'333-333-3333'
p8
ssS'Lelani'
p9
(dp10
g3
S'444-444-4444'
p11
sg5
S'555-555-5555'
p12
sg7
S'666-666-6666'
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you don't indent under the if

Comment: Your code isn't indented correctly.

Comment: print `phonebook_dict` and see if you have `lelani` key in this dictionary.

Comment: That was my mistake when posting, because I have it indented in my actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you need to check if name is in the phonebook_dict

```
def look_up():
    name = raw_input("Name? ")
    if name in phonebook_dict: 
        info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
        print "Found entry for %s: " % (name)
        print "Cell Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Cell"])
        print "Home Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Home"])
        print "Work Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Work"])

    else:
        print "Entry for %s not found." % name
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it!  It was driving me crazy, so I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an indentation on your `if` block.

```
if name in info_dict: #how do i fix this?
#info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
print "Found entry for %s: " % (name)
print "Cell Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Cell"])
print "Home Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Home"])
print "Work Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Work"])
```

Should be:

```
if name in info_dict: #how do i fix this?
    #info_dict = phonebook_dict[name]
    print "Found entry for %s: " % (name)
    print "Cell Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Cell"])
    print "Home Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Home"])
    print "Work Phone Number: %s" % (info_dict["Work"])
```

Without the indentation, those print statements will always run, meaning it will try to index your dictionary whether the `name` is in the dictionary or not.

Comment: shouldn't the else: clasue also be indented?

Comment: That was my mistake in posting the code.  I have it indented in my actual code, but it still was not working.